# Which chapter depicts Doraemon and Nobita on Easter Island?

Tags: doraemon

This one is from a *Doraemon* manga and the story appears to be called 'Battle on Easter Island'.

[image: Doraemon and Nobita on Easter Island with Moai statue on the background]

Which Chapter is it from and how can I purchase/acquire a copy?

Comment: With "which manga is it from" do you perhaps mean which chapter? As you already kind of answered the which manga it is from part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Battle on Easter Island" appears in the 3rd chapter of "The Devil of Time and Space" arc (時空の魔神), in **the 2nd volume of [*The Doraemons Special*](https://myanimelist.net/manga/76175/The%E2%98%86Doraemons_Special) (ザ・ドラえもんズ スペシャル) manga**.

The arc's storyline revolves around Nostradamus' "1999 prophecy".

> [**Nostradamus Arc**](https://doraemon.fandom.com/wiki/The_Doraemons:_Adventure_in_the_Other_Dimension)
>
> Nostradamus the prophet, who was sealed, escapes from the space and time dimension plot to make his prediction come true about the world's end in 1999. It is up to Doraemon, Nobita and the gang to stop him.

The panel on the question depicts Doraemon and Nobita on Easter Island being attacked by the people who are under the influence of Nostradamus, and Nostradamus himself attacking the group with a rain of thunder.

The series has *not* been licensed in English, so there's no way to acquire it legally. However, for the original Japanese language, it can be purchased on [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/4091493025).

---

References:

- [AniOta Wiki - 時空の魔神(ザ☆ドラえもんズ) (Japanese)](https://www49.atwiki.jp/aniwotawiki/pages/34240.html)

Comment: That is extremely helpful. Are you sure it is available in that specific issue that you have indicated is available on Amazon?

Comment: @IanC based on AniOta Wiki referring to *The Doraemons Special* vol. 2 released in 1997, and [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B6%E3%83%BB%E3%83%89%E3%83%A9%E3%81%88%E3%82%82%E3%82%93%E3%82%BA_%E3%82%B9%E3%83%9A%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A3%E3%83%AB#%E6%9C%AC%E7%B7%A8) stating the ISBN for the vol. 2 (ISBN 4091493025), I'm pretty sure it's the correct item on Amazon (matches the ISBN and the release year).